# How can I use __str__ to change how an attribute of my objects shows up?

Tags: python, string, class

I want the chips my player has to show up as $xxx, but to keep the chips as an int. I tried the code below, but the **str** part is just grey. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, gender, taunt, aggression, hand, chips):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender
        self.taunt = taunt
        self.aggression = aggression
        self.hand = hand
        self.chips = chips

        def __str__(self):
            return "${0}".format(self.chips)
```

Comment: What do you mean it's grey?  What happens when you do `print(Player('','','','','',1))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is unindent the `__str__` function and it will work as normal:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, gender, taunt, aggression, hand, chips):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender
        self.taunt = taunt
        self.aggression = aggression
        self.hand = hand
        self.chips = chips

    # Note the outdent of the function

    def __str__(self):
        return "${0}".format(self.chips)
```

Comment: *facepalm* That was dumb of me. Thanks for helping though!! :) Much appreciated!